# Calculating length of road over different kinds of land cover using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have road network (shapefile polyline) and landcover (polygon).

How can I calculate the length of road that cross different kinds of landcover？

---

According to the answer, I write the following code.

6 kinds of landcover and 35 roads

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

for j in range(1, 7):
    land_cover = "Land_" + str(j)
    for i in range(1, 36):

        # Local variables:
        in_land = "U:\\4_work_space\\LandCover_shp\\" + land_cover + "_Dissolve.shp"
        in_line = "U:\\4_work_space\\Line\\Line_" + str(i) + ".shp"
        out_shp = "U:\\4_work_space\\output\\" + land_cover + str(i) + ".shp"
        out_txt = "U:\\4_work_space\\output\\" + land_cover + str(i) + ".txt"

        print(i)

        # Process: Intersect
        arcpy.Intersect_analysis([in_land, in_line], out_shp, "ALL", "", "INPUT")

        # Process: Add Geometry Attributes
        arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(out_shp, "LENGTH_GEODESIC", "METERS", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")

        arcpy.ExportXYv_stats(out_shp, "LENGTH_GEO", "SPACE", out_txt, "NO_FIELD_NAMES")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One is to use the Intersect tool to capture the attributes of your polygons in a line feature class. I recommend using a geodatabase and not a shapefile to store your output.

[image]

Then view the attributes of the output and sort by landcover by double clicking field heading. Double check to make sure the Shape_length displayed is that of your line feature and not the perimeter of one of your areas.

[image]

Then, in an edit session, select the records that share the same cover type and merge.

[image]

Once you merge the records for each land cover type you should have a table similar to that below. Length is in meters by default.

[image]